# how to transfer the value of a field to another field that attributes compute and inverse (Odoo11)?

Tags: python, odoo, nonetype

I want to transfer the value of a field `days_compensation` to another field `days_compensation_remaining` but which are not in the same models and field 2 has attibutes compute and inverse, I am blocked there, thank you in advance(it's a challenge for everyone haha)
**My code :**

**In this model (hr.employee) :** 
**Classe and field :**

```
class HrEmployee(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'hr.employee'

        days_compensation_remaining = fields.Float(
            'Jours de récupération restant',
            compute='_compute_days_compensation_remaining',
            readonly=True,
            inverse='_inverse_days_compensation_remaining',
            help='Nombre total des jours de récupération ',
            )
```

**Inverse methode :**

```
@api.multi
    def _inverse_days_compensation_remaining(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        compensation_legal_leave = self.company_id.days_compensation_holidays_status_id
        if not compensation_legal_leave:
            raise UserError(_("le type de congé pour les jours de récupération n'est pas défini"))
        diff = self.days_compensation_remaining - compensation_legal_leave.get_days(
            self.id)[compensation_legal_leave.id].get('days_compensation_remaining', 0.0)
        if diff > 0:
            leave = self.env['hr.holidays'].create(
                {
                    'name': 'Allocation for %s' % self.name,
                    'employee_id': self.id,
                    'holiday_status_id': compensation_legal_leave.id,
                    'type': 'add',
                    'holiday_type': 'employee',
                    'number_of_days_temp': diff
                }
            )
            leave.action_approve()
            if leave.double_validation:
                leave.action_validate()
        elif diff < 0:
            raise UserError(_('vous ne pouvez pas réduire le nombre de jours'))
```

**Compute methode :**

```
@api.multi
    def _compute_days_compensation_remaining(self):
        for r in self:
            compensation_legal_leave = r.company_id.days_compensation_holidays_status_id
            if not compensation_legal_leave:
                raise UserError(_("le type de congé pour les jours de récupération n'est pas défini"))
            r.days_compensation_remaining = compensation_legal_leave.get_days(
                r.id)[compensation_legal_leave.id].get('days_compensation_remaining', 0.0)
```

**In this Model (hr.employee.mission) :**

```
class HrMission(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.employee.mission"

    days_compensation =fields.Float(compute='get_compensation', string='Jours de récupération', help="Jours de récupération si la mission contient les jours de repos",
                             required=True, readonly=True, store=True)

    @api.multi
    @api.depends("mission_start_date", "mission_end_date")
    def get_compensation(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.mission_start_date and rec.mission_end_date:
                date_start = datetime.strptime(rec.mission_start_date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
                date_end  = datetime.strptime(rec.mission_end_date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
                delta_day = timedelta(days=1)
                days = {'mon':0,'tue':1,'wed':2,'thu':3,'fri':4,'sat':5,'sun':6}
                dt = date_start
                fri_count = 0
                while dt <= date_end:
                    if dt.weekday() == days['fri']: 
                        fri_count+=1
                    dt += delta_day
                rec.days_compensation = fri_count
```

Comment: Is there a relation between both models?

Comment: In ``hr.employee.mission``, there's ``employee_id`` and not in ``hr.employee``, I'm lost how do I do

Comment: please add your relation and the compute/inverse methods

Comment: You find the complete code above, it's a challenge for everyone, it's new I don't find a case like that

Comment: you forgot `employee_id`

Comment: where I forgot  ``employee_id`` ! to tell you, the model ``hr.employee.mission`` to the field ``employee_id``, there it is in inheritance